# VSCode golang module works only in debug mode / module directory problem?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I have a small golang project with go modules and I have a dependency for github.com/eiannone/keyboard.

If I start my main file with F5 (Start Debugging) it works. If I start it with CTR-F5 (run without debugging) it says it cannot find the package:

```
data/work/advent/d13/main.go:9:2: cannot find package "github.com/eiannone/keyboard" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/eiannone/keyboard (from $GOROOT)
    /home/user/work/go/src/github.com/eiannone/keyboard (from $GOPATH)
```

I can reproduce the same error message from console: Issuing `go run d13/main.go` works if I'm int the module directory (data/work/advent), but fails with the same error message if I issue the command from a different directory.

Is it possible to set the directory to be used in launch.json?

Or is there something else going on?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the 'cannot find package' error is because of the package that you are trying to use aren't present inside the GOROOT and also not in the GOPATH. In order to remove the error, do try to make use of go get command followed by the link of the GitHub package.

```
go get github.com/eiannone/keyboard
```

Comment: The package is installed as a module. I do see `github.com/eiannone/keyboard` if I run `go list -m all`. I see it under `$GOPATH/pkg/mod/...`. Additionally, my program works if I run it manually with `go run` or in VSCode with debugging.

It fails only if I run it without debugging in VSCode.